# Select line with Ctrl/C in PyCharm like Sublime Text does

Tags: python, pycharm, sublimetext3

Is there a way to make PyCharm use Ctrl/C to copy the line where the cursor is if no text is selected (which is what Sublime Text does out of the box). It is really handy feature.

Comment: what's your OS, OS X?

Comment: I'm on Linux--but that doesn't matter. See MattDMo's comment below.

Comment: PyCharm does this now - Copy with no selection = copy entire line, just like sublime. Maybe it's a new feature in PyCharm 5?

Comment: I'm using 5.04 and it doesn't work. I'm using the XWin keymap. What keymap are you using, Seth?

Comment: Ah. I think I figured out PyCharm's behavior on this. In Sublime, you can press Ctrl/C on a line with no text selected then immediately select Ctrl/V to paste a newly copied line. PyCharm does copy the line with Ctrl/C but insists you move off it before you paste with Ctrl/V. Andriy's answer below is the closest, because copying the line is the natural behavior in PyCharm--but move off the line first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When cursor in the line pressing of cntrl + c would select and copy text of libe into buffer ( i am on OS X). Please give more details regarding your OS, pycharm version ,etc if it doesn't work for you.

If you have cmd+C (OS X) You can setup pycharm to copy with cntrl+c by adjusting pycharm keymap for that perform next steps:

1. Go to Pycharm Preferences
2. Open Keymap Settings
3. Find copy shortcut in shortcuts list
4. Double click on it
5. Choos "Add Keyboard Shortcut" option
6. Change to CNTRL +C
7. Save and applky changes

You are done.

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking. The keyboard shortcut `Ctrl-C` is already set for copying selected text. What the OP wants to do is copy the entire line the cursor is on *if no text is selected at all.*

Comment: MattDMo's reply made me realize I didn't ask the question very well. I have edited the question.

Comment: See minor clarification of this answer with OP question.

Comment: @rp., sure thanks for note, i will take  a look on it

Comment: @rp. right now i am using pycharm community edition and when i place cursor on line and press `cntrl+c` it copy line into buffer, does that's behaviour you are talking about ?